# How do I convert a string into ascii in amzi! prolog?

Tags: prolog, ascii, amzi-prolog

so I tried converting strings into ascii with the name/2 and char_codes/2 and so on, but I keep getting things like [0w0061,0w0062,0w0063]
for example.

```
?- name(abc,A).

A = [0w0061,0w0062,0w0063]
```

I want the returned list to be [97,98,99].
any help?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried that isn't working.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield what do you mean? I did post it, I tried the name/2 rule and it returned [0w0061,0w0062,0w0063].
name/2 is built in.

Comment: You are not providing a string to the name rule. Use `?- name('abc',A).`

Comment: @MarkBenningfield it does the same thing.

Comment: See this [article](http://www.amzi.com/manuals/amzi/pro/ref_terms.htm#CharacterLists) Amzi! Prolog stores characters as hexadecimal values with 'w' indicating a wide character. `61` in hex = `97` decimal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ASCII character set and while "wide" is somewhat suggestive, the values are [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) code units, one or two of which encode a [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoint. (This is just like in VB4, VBA, Java, JavaScript, .NET, NCHAR, NVARCHAR, ….) It seems you simply what the convert values from the UTF-16 unit code type to the integer type and display them in decimal.

Answer (score 2):

ok so I got it. 
if I tried for example

```
?- name(abc,A).
```

and it returned this:

```
 A = [0w0061,0w0062,0w0063]
```

I took a returned member and subtracted 0 from it. It looks like this.
for example:

```
?- name(a, A).

A = [0w0061] ,
no
?- A is 0w0061 - 0.

A = 97
```